# Get the value from a variable of a table and INSERT into the new table with extra variable for the new table not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I am testing a SQL Query for a VB.NET project that **INSERT** the details of food into a table for the Add to Cart feature after user select the quantity of the food.

The query will get the food details such as food name and food price from a table called **Food** and it will need to add all the food details into the table called **Cart** together with quantity and subtotal.

I wanted to get the value from **Food** table and some quantity that input by user and **INSERT** into the Cart table.

However, there's an issue that the values that I wanted to add are displaying invalid column name when I test the query in SQL Query compiler.

Here's the error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "Food.Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "Food.foodName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "Food.price" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "Food.price" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'qty'.
```

Here's my SQL Query command.
**Note:The integer and the math calculation is just for testing, I will change to parameterized query in the program.**

```
SELECT * FROM Cart

INSERT INTO Cart (foodID, foodName, foodPrice, [qty], total) 
VALUES (Food.Id, Food.foodName, Food.price, 2, Food.price * qty)
SELECT Id, foodName, price
FROM Food
WHERE foodName = 'BREAKFAST'

SELECT * FROM Cart
```

Here's the table that I created

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cart] (
    [Id]        INT             IDENTITY (100000, 1) NOT NULL,
    [foodID]    INT             NOT NULL,
    [foodName]  VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    [foodPrice] DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [qty]       INT             NOT NULL,
    [total]     DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([foodID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Food] ([Id]),
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Food] (
    [Id]       INT             IDENTITY (100, 1) NOT NULL,
    [foodName] VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [price]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I pretty sure the problem is the variable I put in the **VALUE** is not correct, I am not sure what is the correct way to put the variable from another table into the **VALUE**? Sorry for the question because I am very new to SQL Database.

Comment: Please don't tag indiscriminately

Comment: You can't create a table with a foreign key to a table that doesn't exist yet. Food needs to be created first.

Comment: @Larnu Hi, Larnu, the Food table is created on the above code snippet that I shown.

Comment: *After* `Cart`, so `Cart` will fail to be created

Comment: @Larnu Oh Sorry Larnu, I get what u mean here, it's a little bit misleading. The above code snippet is just I combine 2 of these table into a code snippet to make all the viewers easy to look at, but actually they are not compile in same place, they were seperated. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want something like:

```
INSERT INTO Cart (foodID, foodName, foodPrice, [qty], total) 
    SELECT f.Id, f.foodName, f.price, 2, f.price * qty
    FROM Food f
    WHERE f.foodName = 'BREAKFAST'
```

I don't know where `qty` comes from.  Presumably, you pass that in as a parameter of some sort.

Also, your data model is not normalized and that is a bad thing.  You should just include `foodID` in the cart and look up the rest of the values using `JOIN`.

Comment: Ya, qty is the value that I pass in as a parameter.

Comment: Ohh ya, I totally forgot about the JOIN, let me try it out.

Comment: Hi Gordan, I'm not sure why I am getting an error that says - Invalid column name 'qty' on line 2, which is the qty that we multiply follow the code u shown above, it seems like the qty did not get the value of 2 from the qty that assign before it.

Comment: Ok I understand why it is getting error already, suppose its a value I pass in as a parameter. so the qty should be 2 and not qty, sorry for my mistakes haha. Thanks a lot man.